# Struts2 xwork Type Conversion - Multiple different parameters into one Object

Tags: struts2, type-conversion

Is it possible to convert different paremeters into one object on your action?

Say from my html form, I pass in variables, "firstname", "lastname".  Can I write a type converter that will convert those into a Person object on my action?

I didn't see any examples of this, and I don't see API.  I don't see how I can access the value stack in the StrutsTypeConverter to get to the other variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example :**

```
// JavaBeans
public class Person {
    @Getter @Setter private String firstname;
    @Getter @Setter private String lastname;
}
```

```
// Action
@Setter private Person person;
```

```
// form
<s:form>
  <s:textfield name="person.firstname" />
  <s:textfield name="person.lastname" />
</s:form>
```

Similar example : [**vaannila : Domain Object as JavaBeans Property**](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/object-backed-java-beans-example-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am agree what lschin said.you can use the build in OGNL and value stack combination to achieve what you want.still if u need some specific type conversion machanism here are the details from the Struts2 docs

[Struts2 Type Conversion](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/type-conversion.html)